# My Win 10 PC has a Recovery Partition but it doesn't have System Reserved Partition. How to get System Reserved Partition back?

Tags: windows

My windows 10 PC has Recovery Partition of 300 mb but it doesn't have System Reserved Partition. It might have been deleted accidentally.

Now I am unable to get the latest update of Windows 10, version 1803 amd64 2019-03. It is giving a message "We couldn't update the system reserved partition".

Therefore, I need System Reserved Partition to get the latest updates of Windows 10.

Now, my question is - how do I get back System Reserved Partition?

For your information, I would like to say that I am capable of increasing the volume of System Reserved Partition if it is there.

[image: Here is the image of disk management]

Comment: You should provide a screenshot of your partition layout.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the steps given by Microsoft to fix this problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3086249/we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows

Comment: Can you quote the article, so that this is an answer, not a link only? (This will also make sure the answer stays useful once the article is no longer there - prevents "link rot").